# Calculating the smallest control function (conjuntive normal form)

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

i am trying to calculate the smallest possible control function.

The function from the function table is:

A = NOT(S3) & S2 & S1 v S3 & NOT(S2) & S1 v S3 & S2 & NOT(S1) v S3 & S2 & S1

My solution is:

A = S1 & (NOT(S3) & S2 v S3 & NOT(S2)) v S3 & S2

The right solution is:

A = S1 & S2 v S2 & S3 v S3 & S1

I think the first part of my solution is not in the final stage.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that `X = X v X`. You can use the same term multiple times to produce different factors. For example you combine `NOT(S3) & S2 & S1` with `S3 & S2 & S1` to get `S2 & S1`. But also you combine `S3 & NOT(S2) & S1` with `S3 & S2 & S1` to get `S3 & S1`. Last you combine `S3 & S2 & NOT(S1)` with `S3 & S2 & S1` to get `S3 & S2`.

Easier than manipulating the function directly to get the conjuntive normal form though is using a Karnaugh map. The multiple use of `S3 & S2 & S1` coresponds with overlapping regions in the map.